# SharePoint 365: Updating User-type fields through REST api

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, spfielduser

On my SharePoint online (version 16.0.0.5312), when I retrieve items through REST api: `/some-site/_api/web/lists/getbyTitle('ListName')/items(3)`, the API returns a new property for User-type fields.

I have a user-type field called "AssignedTo" and the SharePoint call returns:

```
{
    Title: 'Title value',
    AssignedToId: 21,
    AssignedToStringId: "21",
    . . .
}
```

The next code creates a new item on this list and "Assign it To" user 21:

```
executor.executeAsync({
    url: "/some-site/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('ListName')/items",
    method: "POST",
    body: "{ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.ListNameListItem' },
        'Title': 'Title value',
        'AssignedToId': 21,
        . . .  },
     headers: { 
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
    },
    success: successHandler,
    error: errorHandler
});
```

Note: We must use field-name + Id in order to refer User and Lookup fields.

If I want to modify this field value on a item, in SharePoint 2013, I use the next code:

```
executor.executeAsync({
    url: "/some-site/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('ListName')/items(2)",
    method: "POST",
    body: "{ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.ListNameListItem' },
        'Title': 'New title value',
        'AssignedToId': 99,
        . . .  },
     headers: { 
        "IF-MATCH": "*",
        "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
        "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
    },
    success: successHandler,
    error: errorHandler
});
```

The problem is that now, on SharePoint online, this code throws a server error!!.

As I mentioned before, a new property appears for User-type fields. The new property is field-name + StringId, and you must use it to update correctly the item value.

For update operations, use the next code:

```
executor.executeAsync({
    url: "/some-site/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('ListName')/items(3)",
    method: "POST",
    body: "{ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.ListNameListItem' },
        'Title': 'New title value',
        'AssignedToStringId': '99',
        . . .  },
     headers: { 
        "IF-MATCH": "*",
        "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
        "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
    },
    success: successHandler,
    error: errorHandler
});
```

Don't forget to assign the value as a string.

This only apply to update operations. For new items, I must keep using "AssignedToId" property.

Someone knows this new behavior about "...StringId" properties?
It's just a bug of the new 2016 version or a definitive guideline.

Thanks,
Pau

Answer (score 1):

The user-type field called `AssignedTo` is a lookup field which uses the ID of the user (Username) you have entered.

So you will definitely get the `ID` or you can only set the ID inplace of username.

That is not a bug of `new 2016 version`